# How to upgrade pandas from 16 on linux-armv7l

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi, 32-bit, armv7

I use miniconda on my pi.
it works well on python 2.7 and pandas 0.16
But the anaconda packages for linux-armv7l 32bit only support 0.16.2
I need to use the function rolling in series.
how to upgrade pandas to higher than 0.18.0?

Answer (score 0):

Find solution from here
https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/49

https://anaconda.org/seibert/pandas

use

```
conda install -c seibert pandas=0.18.1
```